# Hide parent div using jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I need some help with hiding the parent div using jQuery.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="team-member">
    <div class="team-member-info">
        <h3 class="team-member-name">Ann</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery I have so far:

```
if ($('.team-member-info .team-member-name:contains("Ann")').length > 0) {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is, If ".team-member-name" contains the word "Ann", get rid of the entire div, which is ".team-member"

The first line of the jQuery works fine but the second line doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to show us the whole function, so we can see the scope of `$(this)` because it is not the `if` statement that assigns it

Comment: that is my entire function. do i need to add something?

Comment: In the code you've shown, `this` doesn't refer to the DOM object you want to hide. For reference, see MDN's documentation on the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Given your code, you're in the "global context".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need if-block here. Just select and hide:

```
$('.team-member-info .team-member-name:contains("Ann")').closest('.team-member').hide()
```

If jQuery doesn't find any `.team-member-name` containing "Ann" inside it won't hide anything anyway.

Also note, that because you want to walk two levels up, you can't use [$.fn.parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) (only first level ancestor). Instead you should either use [$.fn.parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) or [$.fn.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: shouldn't you also be able to use `.parent()` in this scenario?

Comment: it would have to be `.parent().parent()` to hide the team-member element

Comment: @Adjit No, because parent only takes direct parent, but not grand-parents like we need in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the **if** statment, because `:contains()` will only find that `div` containing `Ann` and will **hide** the parent `div` if that `div` has `Ann`, so no need for if statement here.

Here is working **snippet**.

```js
$(function(){
   $('.team-member-info .team-member-name:contains("Ann")').parent().parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-member">
    <div class="team-member-info">
        <h3 class="team-member-name">Ann</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah! you are right ! that is the way to hide `.team-member`, but you haven't mention that in your question. Any way i updated my answer :)

Comment: your edit worked perfectly. thanks! i am marking this as a solution along with @dfsq 's solution since both work.

Comment: damn unfortunately I can only mark one solution as the answer. the best I can do is give you an upvote!

Comment: No problem! we are here to solve problems, and we did it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't go with complex jQuery selectors (because of multiple reasons), do something like:

```
var $temp_team_member = $('.team-member-info .team-member-name');
if(/Ann/.test( $temp_team_member.text() ) ){
    $temp_team_member.parent().hide();
}
```

Here you're creating variable and catching `.team-member-info .team-member-name`. In case it contains 'Ann' as text, your action is prerformed.

EDIT:
code sample edited to suite "contains Ann" (not *is Ann*) clause.

[Working pen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXNvwZ)

Comment: It may not work because it assumes text that consists *only* of the exact word "Ann", rather than text that *includes* the word "Ann". (i.e. `=== 'Ann'`)

Answer (score 0):

what is $(this) referring to? Is your if statement inside a function or is it on its own? because in this code, $(this) isn't referring to **.team-member-info**

Comment: This is the only answer so far that attempts to explain the problem.

Comment: i only used $this because it is what I found in someone else's solution. I am pretty new to jQuery

Comment: @cup_of No judgment on you; you asked a fine question. I just think it's important for answers include an explanation of the problem in addition to any alternate solutions. So, this answer is important, too.

Comment: i understand ill keep that in mind for my next questoin thanks @showdev

Comment: I was only asking to help you answer the question as precisely as possible. I didn't mean it in a degrading way. I was new to jQuery once and I cared to understand the basics to be able to go further. I'm still learning everyday.

Answer (score 0):

.closest() is deprecated and .parent() only traverses one level up. I would suggest doing the following:

```
$('.team-member-info .team-member-name:contains("Ann")').parents('div.team-member').hide();
```

Comment: I believe `closest()` is depreciated *only* in the functionality where it accepts a `context` parameter. See [`.closest(selectors[,context])`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest2).